# Second derivative test (another)

Tags: calculus

In the second derivate test,
$$D=(f_{xx}\times f_{yy})-f_{xy}^{2}$$
$$D_{u}^{2}f=f_{xx}\times \Bigl(h + \frac{f_{xy}}{f_{xx}}\times k\Bigr)^{2}+\frac{k^{2}}{f_{xx}}\times \Bigl(f_{xx}\times f_{yy}-f_{xy}^{2}\Bigr)$$
I have already understood the first and second consequences:

1) If  $D\gt 0$ and $f_{xx}(a;b)\gt0$, $f(a;b)$ is a local minimum:

For the facts that anything squared is positive or null, $D\gt 0$ and $f_{xx}\gt0$,  $D_{u}^{2}f\gt0$. So for a point (a;b) that $f_{x}(a;b)=0$ and $f_{y}(a;b)=0$ , (a;b) is a local minimum.

2) If  $D\gt 0$ and $f_{xx}(a;b)\gt0$, $f(a;b)$ is a local minimum:

For the facts that anything squared is positive or null, $D\gt 0$ and $f_{xx}\lt0$,  $D_{u}^{2}f\lt0$. So for a point (a;b) that $f_{x}(a;b)=0$ and $f_{y}(a;b)=0$ , (a;b) is a local maximum.

But I didn't understand the third,

3)If $D\lt0$  isn't a local  minimum nor a local maximum.

Answer (score 1):

$D$ is actually the *determinant of the Hessian* $H$ of $f$ (here, $H$ refers to the Hessian of $f$ **at $(a,b)$**). There is a theorem that (for twice continuously differentiable functions $f$) if $(a,b)$ is a local minimiser of $f$, then $H$ must be positive semi-definite (all eigenvalues of $H$ non-negative), and if $(a,b)$ is a local maximiser, then $H$ must be negative semi-definite (all eigenvalues of $H$ non-positive). If $D < 0$, then since $D$ is the product of the two eigenvalues of $H$, $H$ must have one positive eigenvalue and one negative eigenvalue. Hence $H$ is neither positive semi-definite nor negative-definite, so $(a,b)$ is neither a local minimiser nor a local maximiser.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the example:
$$
f(x,y)=x^2+4xy+y^2.
$$
At the point $(0,0)$, we have
$$
f_x=f_y=0,
$$
$$
f_{xx}=f_{yy}=2, \quad f_{xy}=4.
$$
It is clear that $D=-12 <0$. Note that
$$
f(x,y)=(x+2y)^2-3y^2.
$$
Hence, for $h>0$ small, one has
$$
f(-2h,h)=-3h^2<0=f(0,0).
$$
Therefore, $f$ does not have a local minimum at $(0,0)$.